# How to program a symfony webapp to execute something automatically depending on dates

Tags: symfony, service, notifications

I am building a web application with symfony2 ,and I have a problem.
The user is subscribed to an event and I want my application to automatically notify him one day before the day of the event .
I have the necessary tables ; users, events, inscri_event which represents the association between user and event holding extra fields and I have already implented a service to notify a list of users passed as argument.

How to tell symfony to, automatically, check for the current date and once it's a day before the date of an event, notifiy the subscribed users.

Please tell me what I need to do exactly or at least point me to the right path. I don't even know what I should type in Google. I'm new to Symfony 2, so please bear with me.
Thank you in advance.
there is my fonction

```
 public function notifierAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $seances = $em->getRepository('OCUserBundle:Seance')->findAll();
    foreach ($seances as $s)
    {
        $datenow= new DateTime();
        $interval = $datenow->diff($s->getDate(),true)->format('d');
        if ($interval=1 )
        {
        $inscritformation = $em->getRepository('OCUserBundle:InscriFormation')->findBy($s->getFormation()->getId());
    $notificateur = $this->get('Notificateur');
    $repository2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('OCUserBundle:UserApprenant');
    foreach ($inscritformation as $insfor) {
        $user = $insfor->getApprenant()->getId();
        $apprenant = $repository2->findBy(array('id' => $user));
        $notificateur->notifier('la formation dont vous ete inscrit est demain' . $s->getFormation()->getTitre(), $apprenant, $s->getFormation()->getId(),'alarme');
    }
```

}}}

Comment: You need to build a cron job which will hit some action of your controller, in cron you need to query events according to your criteria (notification one day before) , now get your users and send email its better to use swiftmailer's spool option because once you have many users then directly sending  mail to all users can take much time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `Command` and run it with `cron`. For example:

```
class NotifyUsersCommand extends Command
{
    public function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('notify:users')
            // more configuration
        ;
    }

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        // Find all users with event date = tomorrow
        $seances = $em->getRepository('OCUserBundle:Seance')
                      ->findAllEventsWithDateTomorrow();

        foreach ($seances as $s) {
           // send notifications
        }
    }
}
```

In SeanceRepository (or whatever the repository name is)

```
public function findAllEventsWithDateTomorrow()
{
    $tomorrow = new DateTime();
    $tomorrow->modify('+1 day'); // 1 day from now

    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()
               ->createQueryBuilder()
               ->where('u.date < :tomorrow') 
               ->setParameter(':tomorrow', $tomorrow->format(/*datetime format*/));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Then you configure cron to run the command every minute (check your php binary path with `which php`)

```
# crontab -e

* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/app/console notify:users
```

Crontab reference http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

If you are using Windows, cron equivalent is `schtasks`

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "Notify users" /tr "C:\path\to\php.exe C:\path\to\your\app\console notify:users"
```

schtasks reference https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx

Comment: I have all ready do what you told me it works but the table of notification in the database still empty I don't know where is the problem :/

Comment: Did you check if the command is executed and `findAllEventsWithDateTomorrow` result is correct?

Comment: So... that's it. There's your answer. The problem must be somewhere else.